# (SQL) realizar Inner Join por medio de condicional

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, condiciones, mariadb

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta de tres tablas en mi MariaDB de un gimnasio:

```
Clases
Instructores
Usuarios
```

Lo que me pide el query es lo siguiente:

> *"Conocer cual es la clase que tiene mas alumnos y desplegar  “clase“, 
>   “nombre completo del instructor” incluyendo además  “nombres de los
>   alumnos”".*

He podido realizar el siguiente despliegue: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de consulta que utilicé:

```
select usuarios.Nombre, clases.Nombre_Clase, instructores.Nombre
from((clases
inner join usuarios on clases.Clase_ID = usuarios.Clases)
inner join instructores on clases.ID_instructor = instructores.ID);
```

Pero ¿Cómo puedo desplegar la clase que tiene más alumnos?? en éste caso que sea la de Box?

No soy muy bueno en base de datos, pero ¿Se puede aplicar algún tipo de contador?

P.D. la última columna del lado derecho es la de instructores, la del izquierdo es de alumnos.

Comment: es un ejercicio? por favor agrega el codigo que intentaste..

Comment: He agregado el Query que use en la imagen.
El motor de Busqueda utilizado es MariaDB.

Comment: para poder construir el query correcto faltaria un poco de estructura de las tablas.. pero lo que deberias hacer es agregar una clausula where = a un select que agrupe por clase y cuente la cantidad de apariciones de alumnos y quedarte con el mayor de eso.

Comment: La clausula 'where' inspeccionará desde la tabla usuarios, para ver contar las suscripciones de clases no? Ya que es en la que invoco la llave primaria de clases.

Comment: La clausula where sirve para que se filtren solo la clase que vos queres

Answer (score 2):

He resuelto el Query, para los que tengan una situación similar:

```
select from usuarios.Nombre, clases.Nombre_Clase, instructores.Nombre
from((clases
inner join usuarios on clases.Clase_ID = usuarios.Clases)
inner join instructores on clasese_instructor = instructores.ID)
where usuarios.Clases = '1' ; //Número de clase
```

El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias gbianchi, por tu apoyo.

Comment: Dudo mucho que esa query tal que así funcione bien, porque estás metiendo a mano la clase que tú quieres, no la que tiene más alumnos. Quizás ahora mismo da la casualidad de que es la que has puesto, pero puede cambiar en cualquier momento.